# Using REST EPA in Python code gives an error What is wrong with this code?

Tags: python-3.x, api, rest

REST API document

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
curl --location --request POST 'https://zaya.io/api/v1/links' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {api_key}' \
--data-urlencode 'url={url}'
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

My Code

```
import requests
api="https://zaya.io/api/v1/links"
API_KEY = "################################################"
data = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)"
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + API_KEY}
r = requests.get(api, data=data, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

The error I face:

```
{"message":"You are not logged in.","status":403}
```

Comment: What error? You have to be more specific.

Comment: show me this error:
{"message":"You are not logged in.","status":403}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Mistake 1 **You are doing a `GET` where the document asks you to send a `POST`.**
- Mistake 2 **The data must be form URL encoded, must be key-value pairs**
- Mistake 3 **You must set the proper Content-Type header**
- Bigger mistake ***Do not post your API key on public forums.***

The code below works fine, with the above corrections.

```
import requests

api = "https://zaya.io/api/v1/links"

# Never reveal your API key
API_KEY = "##########################################################"

# Data is URL Form encoded, so it must be key-value pair
data = {"url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)"}

# Add proper headers
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + API_KEY, 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

# Most important. CURL says POST, you did GET 
r = requests.post(api, data=data, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
# Gives proper response
```